# Using C# assembly in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, clr

I've got a c# class library that I call from an asp.net application. The assembly calculates grades for students and performs calculations using datatables and such.

How can I use this assembly in SQL Server 2005 and call it once for each record in a database table? I want to re-use functionality and avoid writing the thing in T-SQL.

Answer (score 4):

To use .Net assemblies in SQL Server you need to enable CLR Integration in SQL server. This section on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131046(SQL.90).aspx) has some good examples.

As you have the logic already in .Net wouldn't it be better to do all the work there?  As your application grows you'll be much better off keeping all you business logic in code and using the database as a store of data.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily mean that if you have processing you have to keep it in the code. What if you use the database in that processing and you have many round trips to it and that's why you chose to process the data in the db itself.